# jQuery, submit form with a button

Tags: jquery

I have a form which contains the method "POST" and action ="abc.php" and button type of `<input type ="button">`
I have a handler when i cick that button i want to send a request to abc.php but nothing is happening no action is being prformed.I dont want to change the `<input type ="button">` to `<input type="submit>`.How do i submit the Form .Here is the code

```
<form name= "form1" id ="form1" action ="abc.php" method="post">
<input type ="button" id="mybutton" value ="Add"> 
......
//All form Elements.
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Load all elements
});
$("#mybutton").click(function(e){
    alert(true);
    //$("#frmpohdr").submit();
});
```

The Above Statement is giving error and i know we need to have button type of submit 
for this method.How do i submit the Form to the abc.php when i click the button .I have tried all $.ajax methods

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried putting all the code inside ready?

Also, if the form's id is form 1 you should do this:

```
$("#form1").submit();
```

And to avoid the buttons default's behaviour you should also add this link inside click's function:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

I also recommend you having a look at jQuery Form Plugin: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/

I hope i helped :)

Comment: "if the form's **id** is form1" - the # selector in jQuery is for ids, not names.

Answer (score 3):

```
jq("#showDetail").click(function() {
            jq('#formName').submit();
});
<input type="button" id="showDetail" class="secondarybutton" value="Done" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You will either submit the form through the HTML form (i.e. change the input type = submit)
Or you could use the 
[$.post/$.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Post)

Comment: The question is about submitting the form using `button` and its not good to suggest to change the attribute to `submit`